# pygame set cursor back to default

Tags: python, windows, pygame, cursor

I want to have a click-cursor in my program.

I used `pygame.mouse.set_cursor(pygame.cursors.Cursor(pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_HAND))` when the user hovers on one of the buttons, that changes the cursor to a click-cursor and that's all fine.
**My question is how can I get the cursor back to it's default?**

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html#pygame.cursors.Cursor):

> Creating a cursor without passing arguments
>
> In addition to the cursor constants available and described above, you can also call `pygame.cursors.Cursor()`, and your cursor is ready (doing that is the same as calling `pygame.cursors.Cursor(pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_ARROW)`. Doing one of those calls actually **creates a system cursor using the default native image**.

So you can get the default cursor with

```py
pygame.mouse.set_cursor(pygame.cursors.Cursor())
```